# Check if update statement was successful

Tags: c#, sql, verify

I have the following method that sets an object to a specific status (it sets a column value of a specific row to '4' :

C#

```
 void setObjectToFour(int objectID)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("setObjectToFour", conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            })
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@objectID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = objectID;
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

SQL:

```
...
AS
BEGIN
    Update [DB_OBJECT].[dbo].[object_table]
    SET status = 4
    WHERE id = @objectID

END
```

The problem is that the DB_OBJECT DB is not managed by us and is the DB of a piece of software.

The followed problem is that the query from above not always works (and we haven't figured out why) and I were thinking about how we could 'force' or 'check' if the row was updated.

Is it smart to do it as follow?:

1 - Create new C# Method `Check` and stored procedure `getStatus` that retrieves the status of the object

2 - I will put both methods from above in a `do while` until the status is 4.

Is this a smart approach?

Comment: "command.ExecuteNonQuery();" already gives you the answer. just check if it is not 0, it it is 0 then nothing has been updated or changed

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery will return the number of rows affected.

Comment: This would mean that I could call the same method inside my method? like `int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsAffected == 0)
                {
setObjectToFour(objectID)
                   
                }`

Answer (score 8):

[ExecuteNonQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns the number of rows affected.

```
int recordAffectd = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (recordAffectd > 0)
{
    // do something here  
}
```

Comment: This would mean that I could call the same method inside my method? like `int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsAffected == 0)
                {
setObjectToFour(objectID)
                   
                }`

Comment: @user3127554. exactly.

Comment: @user3127554 but ensure to not do this unconditionally. If it will return 0 many times in a row - you might have stackoverflow exception which will crash the whole process.

Answer (score 2):

**ExecuteNonQuery()** does not return data at all: only the number of rows affected by an insert, update, or delete.

try this

```
if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() !=  0)
{
    // more code 
}
```